# System and Preferences Icon vanished from menu bar

Tags: menu

On my ubuntu12.04 screen launcher, System and Preferences Icon has got vanished..

there used to be system and preferences icon on left vertical panel(launcher), now that is not visible, How to add it again to menubar??
right now i am using " gnome-control-center "this command to open that, but i want it back on launcher,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the icon locked to the launcher, a simple way would be to open the System and Preferences window from your dash (open the menu and type "system"). Then once it's open, right-click the icon in the launcher and click "Lock to launcher". Then, the icon will stay there even after the program is closed.